# MVC4 Ajax load records on windows scroll

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Using MVC4 and Ajax. I am loading 5 records and on windows scroll down load the next 5 records ..etc

Controller: (works)

```
    public JsonResult FetchData(int pageIndex = 0)
    {
      var model = ...
      ViewBag.count = pageIndex*2;

      return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View

javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            FetchDataFromServer();
        }
    });
});

  function FetchDataFromServer() {
    var Id = $(".postcount").attr("Id");
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("FetchData")',
        data: { pageIndex: Id },
        datatype: 'application/json',
        success: function () {
            //?
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
  });


 <div id="result">
   @Html.Partial("_ResultList",Model)
</div>
```

The first time the model gets passed to the partial view and data successfully loads. On scroll down the Action FeachData gets executed and I can see the data gets retrieved successfully.

My question when FeachData method passes the model, How do I pass the model to the Partial View and append to the existing records?

partial view excepts a model and has a @foreach (var item in Model){..} that loops and displays the data.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you model is a collection, use `.Take()` and `.Skip()` to filter the records you want and return a partial view based on the results.

Controller

```
public ActionResult FetchData(int skipCount, int takeCount)
{
  var model = db.MyObjects.OrderBy(x => x.SomeProperty).Skip(skipCount).Take(takeCount);
  if (model.Any())
  {
    return PartialView("_ResultList", model);
  }
  else
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Script

```
var skipCount = 5; // start at 6th record (assumes first 5 included in initial view)
var takeCount = 5; // return new 5 records
var hasMoreRecords = true;

function FetchDataFromServer() {
  if (!hasMoreRecords) {
    return;
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("FetchData")',
    data: { skipCount : skipCount, takeCount: takeCount },
    datatype: 'html',
    success: function (data) {
      if (data === null) {
        hasMoreRecords = false; // signal no more records to display
      } else {
        $("#result").append(data);
        skipCount += takeCount; // update for next iteration
      }
    },
    error: function () {
      alert("error");
    }
  });
}
```

**Edit: Alternative using JSON**

Controller

```
public ActionResult FetchData(int skipCount, int takeCount)
{
  var model = db.MyObjects.OrderBy(x => x.SomeProperty).Skip(skipCount).Take(takeCount);
  return Json( new { items = model, count = model.Count() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Script

```
var skipCount = 5; // start at 6th record (assumes first 5 included in initial view)
var takeCount = 5; // return new 5 records
var hasMoreRecords = true;

function FetchDataFromServer() {
  if (!hasMoreRecords) {
    return;
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("FetchData")',
    data: { skipCount : skipCount, takeCount: takeCount },
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.Count < 5) {
        hasMoreRecords = false; // signal no more records to display
      }
      $.each(data.items, function(index, item) {
        // assume each object contains ID and Name properties
        var container = $('<div></div>');
        var id = $('<div></div>').text($(this).ID);
        container.append(id);
        var name = $('<div></div>').text($(this).Name);
        container.append(name);
        $("#result").append(container);
      });
      skipCount += takeCount; // update for next iteration
    },
    error: function () {
      alert("error");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How would you check if there no more records to retrieve to just display a message and not to call server ActionResult FetchData?

Comment: If you were to return JSON containing the data (rather than a partial view) and construct the html on he client, you could add an additional property indicating if there were no more records to display (i.e if the query returned less than 5 records). If returning a partial view, I'm not sure of the best way - perhaps if the query returns zero records, return null instead of a view so that you could check if the returned value is null, then set a flag so that the ajax is not called again

Comment: thanks, so if I change the return to  JSON i.e. return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); how would I pass the model object to the partial view or to the main view and extract the data?

Comment: I'll update my answer shortly. I'll just assume your model has 2 properties `ID` and `Name` and that you render then in `<div>` tags.

Comment: @Roman, Updated answer to show possible solution using JSON result. Note also updated original to show how you can test if there are any more items using a partial view.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. do you prefer JSON or PartialView. Is it the same thing just different way of doing it?

Comment: Achieves the same result. I personally prefer JSON because it gives me a bit more control and the payload is smaller, but it can mean a bit more code in the script to generate the html (its duplicating the code you have already generated in the partial view) so maybe in this case the partial view might be better. The script code means that when say the last 3 items are returned, the partial view option will make one more call which is unnecessary but its probably negligible.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Json` return partial view from the action:

```
public ActionResult FetchData(int pageIndex = 0)
    {
      var model = ...
      ViewBag.count = pageIndex*2;

      return View("_ResultList",model);
    }
```

and in Success callback you will have the response html, you need to append it to that div by using `append()`:

```
success: function (response) {
            $("#result").append(response);
        }
```

You can also see [this post. **Infinite Scroll Paging in Asp.net mvc 4**](http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2013/12/infinite-scroll-paging-in-aspnet-mvc-4.html)

Comment: I need to pass Model to thew partial view and inside my partial view I have a @foreach (var item in Model){} that displays the data. How do I do that?

Comment: @Roman see edited post and refer to the link in the post. it will help you

Comment: I checked the link, sorry I am still confused on how to append, the response is an object a model(contains all the records) how do I pass to the partial view a model?

Comment: You have to return partial view from action of ajax call not model only partial view is rendered as html and it will be appended in the div